# Using variable for database name

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am having difficulty in using a variable name for the database. The below script searches through all databases and finds database that match a certain condition. The matching databases are added to table #t.
I then loop through each database by setting the @DB1 to each database in turn. The problem I'm getting is when it comes to using the database name in @DB1. Any idea how I can get each of my matching databases to update?

```
create table #t (
    ID int IDENTITY,DBName sysname not null
)
go
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?]; if OBJECT_ID(''dbo.SDE_server_config'') is not null insert into #t (DBName) select ''?'''



Declare @RowCount int
Declare @Counter int
Declare @DB1 varchar(max)

set @RowCount = (Select Count(*) from #t)
set @Counter=0


While @Counter <= @RowCount
Begin
select @Counter = @Counter + 1


set @DB1 =  = (select DBName FROM #t WHERE ID = @COUNTER)

:SETVAR DatabaseName @DB1



USE $(DatabaseName);

UPDATE dbo.SDE_server_config
        SET num_prop_value=0
        WHERE prop_name=CONNECTIONS;

End
```

Comment: Kim and Aaron Bertrand make a good and correct point below that sp_MSforeachDB is not supported and has some issues. It doesn't always operate over the entire list of databases.

Answer (score 2):

You dont really need a loop and there is no need to use the undocumented `sp_MSforeachdb` as [there is a better alternative to it - written by Aaron Bertrand](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).

You can use below tsql - Run in SSMS by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

```
set nocount on

select 'if OBJECT_ID(''dbo.SDE_server_config'') is not null'+char(10)+'begin '+char(10)+' UPDATE ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.SDE_server_config SET num_prop_value=0
        WHERE prop_name=CONNECTIONS;' + char(10) + 'end '+char(10)+ 'else print ''there is nothing to update ...!;'''
from sys.databases
where database_id > 4
    and state_desc = 'ONLINE'
```

You can put above `select` statement in a variable and do and `EXEC` and save it in a `.sql` file and then use sqlcmd to just directly call that `.sql` file and run it on multiple servers.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach: (different from [@Kin's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106761/1186) mostly in that you don't have to copy/paste the output or save to a .sql file):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name)
  + N'.sys.objects WHERE name = N''SDE_server_config'')
  UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.SDE_server_config
    SET num_prop_value = 0 WHERE prop_name = ''CONNECTIONS'';'
FROM sys.databases;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be to add the update statement into the the string executed by sp_MSforeachDB:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb 'use [?]; 
    if OBJECT_ID(''dbo.SDE_server_config'') is not null 
    update UPDATE dbo.SDE_server_config
    SET num_prop_value=0
    WHERE prop_name=CONNECTIONS;'
```

If you need to do something more complicated (not just an update statement), you can use dynamic sql:

```
--Put this with other variable declarations
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
```

...

```
--Put this in WHILE loop
SET @SQL = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DB1) + ' 
    update UPDATE dbo.SDE_server_config
    SET num_prop_value=0
    WHERE prop_name=CONNECTIONS;'
EXEC (@SQL);
```

Comment: Please note that `sp_MSforeachdb` is undocumented and not supported.

Comment: And broken, too!